# "Back to the top" button with BASE tag

Tags: html

In my HTML, I am currently using the following BASE tag to simplify file management:

```
<base href="../" target="_blank" />
```

I am willing to add a 'top of the page' button at the bottom of a page. The following line will not work, probably because the base is one directory up.

```
<a id="back2top" class="button" href="#">Back to the top</a>
```

So I tried this instead (where the href points to the page itself):

```
<a id="back2top" class="button" href="fr/1_calendar.html">Back to the top</a>
```

However, when I click on the button, the bowser does 2 things:
- it goes to the top of the page (what I want)
- and opens a new window (tested on IE and Chrome).

Is there a way I can:
- either override BASE so that href="#" works
- or prevent the second window from opening

Comment: It seems that the `<base>` does more harm than good here. Can't you get rid of it? Anyway, the new window problem can be solved without Javascript by using `target=_top` in the "top of page" link.

Comment: Here is an interesting discussion on the pros and cons of using base: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag

Comment: Thanks for these interesting comments. I'm going to try to get rid of the base. But in my case it is a good way to keep a common "images" directory along with multiple directories containing the pages themselves: "website_en", "website_fr", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `<base href=...>`, it by definition affects all relative URLs. It cannot be overridden; the only way to prevent it from affecting a URL is to use a relative URL.

So if `<base href=...>` is used, the only way in HTML to set up a link to the start of a document is to use one with a `href` specifying the absolute (full) URL of the document itself.

On the other hand, [by the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-BASE) the `href` value in `base` tag must be an absolute URL. So whatever the tag does in your case is to be classified as undocumented error handling.

Comment: I get it. About the relative href, I knew about it, but I am running in a controlled environment. The mini-site is the help section of an android app. I'll try to find a better way, for the sake of stability.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use javascript this would work:

```
function goToTop(){
    window.scrollTo(0,0)
    return false; //prevent page from reloading
}
```

Your html could look like:

```
<a href="javascript:goToTop()">Back to the top</a>
```

or:

```
<a onclick="javascript:goToTop()">Back to the top</a>
```

Comment: I am not currently using javascript. And would prefer not to us it.